# Does moving apps to SD card make launcher load time longer?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, external-sd, performance, launcher

I've been experiencing longer and longer times for the launcher to load when removing my phone (Moto Droid, 2.2.1) from the car dock or media dock, or when running the clock application for a long time (overnight).   I understand from other questions on this site that the delay is related to memory management time to re-load the launcher, but the time seems to be getting longer and longer.

I've been moving more apps to the SD card over time and was wondering if the launcher is requiring more startup time to fetch icons from the SD card?    If so, would it help to put SD apps in a folder or remove them from the home screens in order to speed up the load time for the launcher?

I have not added any new widgets for quite a while, but I do have a couple Tasker profiles, although I don't think the additional slowdown corresponds to changes in the Tasker setup.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is not really with loading the launcherbut remounting the sdcard.  You say it happens when you take it out of the dock?  Does the dock connect to your computer? If so does it put your phone into USB transfer mode?

Comment: No, the dock just connects it to the charger and causes the clock app to load.  It doesn't connect to a computer.

Comment: When you remove your phone from the dock do you see an icon like the one in this picture?  http://i18.photobucket.com/albums/b141/CasetB/device1.png

Comment: @CaseyB - no, I don't.

Comment: Hmmm.  Then I don't know what the issue may be.  The problem I'm having is that I don't understand why the launcher would need to be reloaded after being docked.

Comment: In the case of either dock, the launcher goes unused for extended periods of time -- typically overnight in the media dock, 30+ minutes in the car dock -- so it would seem reasonable for the memory management logic to remove it from memory.

Comment: It would only remove it from memory if something else needed it.  That would make sense inthe car if you're listening to music or getting directions but it shouldn't happen at night.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the lag may have been related to being low on internal storage.    After deleting some seldom-used apps (all the could be moved to SD already had been), the overall phone performance is much better, including the launcher.